# "SDE error 6" when publishing GeoServer layer

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase

I have successfully created an ArcSDE datastore in GeoServer 2.2.4. When I try to publish a feature class in the SDE database, the "Compute from data" link returns nothing, and the "Compute from native bounds" link produces the following error.

```
Error computing the geographic bounds:[SDE error 6][Error desc=UNKNOWN ERROR CODE. ][Extended desc= ]
```

The Native SRS says UNKNOWN in the text box but has the correct system to the right "GCS_WGS_1984...".

Because I do not have either of the bounding boxes filled in, obviously I can not save the layer.

I have tried feature classes with other coordinate systems, deleting and re-creating the datastore and creating whole new feature classes. Extensive searching on the internet has not turned up any kind of solution.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your issue is, I have never used Geoserver.  I can tell you that a SDE error code 6 is a client IO error.

*SE_EXIT_CLIENT_IO_ERROR 6
An error was encountered in setting up communications to the client. Make sure the client is still running.*

Here is a list of SDE return codes:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/api/capi/returncodes_incl.htm

If you are using a three tier connection I would check you application server.